# Show that the function has a pole of order at most $n$.

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification

> Suppose $f(z)$ has an isolated singularity at $z_0$. If $(z-z_0)^nf(z)$ is bounded near $z_0$ then $z_0$ is either removable or a pole of order at most $n$.

My attempt: Let $g(z) = (z-z_0)^nf(z)$. Then $|g(z)|<M$ for some $M$. So $g(z)$ has a removable singularity at $z_0$. So we may write $g(z) = a_0+a_1(z-z_0)+\cdots$. Let $a_m$ be the first nonzero coefficient. From this, can I directly conclude that $f(z) = a_m(z-z_0)^{m-n}+a_{m+1}(z-z_0)^{m-n+1}+\cdots$ so that if $m\geq n$ then it has a removable singularity and if $m<n$ then it has pole at most $n$.

Comment: Seems to be correct. What argument you use to conclude that $g$ has removable singularity at $z_0$?

Comment: @YathirajSharma Riemann's singularity theorem

Comment: I wonder if I can just directly conclude $f$ can be expressed like that

Comment: If $f(z) = \frac{g(z)}{(z-z_0)^n}$, where $g(z)$ is analytic, then $f(z)$ can be analytic or has a pole of order at most $n$ at $z_0$. The series that you have given is the Laurent series expansion of $f$ at $z_0$.